# Am I to always use quotes for attribute values for the Elements in the Angular Component HTML Template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to resolve an issue with our DataTable and am not too familiar with the Element tag usage such as the following.

Notice that all values have quotes around them but I have also seen examples without quotes around the values.

**Are quotes always to be used?**

Would I ever use {{variableRef}} in an element tag?

```
<ngx-datatable
    #myTable2
    class="bootstrap"
    [rows]="datatable2.rows"
    [cssClasses]="datatable2.cssClasses"
    columnMode="force"
    [reorderable]="true"
    [headerHeight]="38"
    [footerHeight]="40"
    [rowHeight]="30"
    [externalPaging]="false"
    [limit]="5"
    [offset]="datatable2.pageNumber"
    [count]="datatable2.rows.length"
    [virtualization]="false"
    [scrollbarV]="false"
    (page)="onPage($event)"
  >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are quotes always to be used?

Yes, it is strongly recommended to always use quotes. Though there are cases when the application might work without them, it is pretty much advised to be consistent with it.

> Would I ever use {{variableRef}} in an element tag?

No. You either pass a member reference (`[cssClasses]="datatable2.cssClasses"`) or a value (`[rowHeight]="30"`), or some kind of expression, but you don't use interpolation in such case.